# Using JQuery Document with Imagemap Areas

Tags: jquery, html

I have this image map:

```
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/f06u7v2psku7h9fo2q2manmva5_mapfinal_002.png" border="0" width="500" height="500" orgWidth="500" orgHeight="500" usemap="#image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524">
<area id="Mexico" alt="Pioneer Mexico" title="Mexico" href="#" shape="rect" coords="143,372,193,422" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="#opener"    />
<area shape="rect" coords="498,498,500,500" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_28593" />
</map>
```

I'm using the following jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});</script>
```

However, when I click on my image, it seems like I get no reaction. How do I hook up the event in the script to the imagemap?

Comment: Why is this considered a bad question? I cannot find any examples on Google that illustrate this...

Comment: Because you're not showing any of your code, explaining what you've tried, what problems you're having, etc.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin!

Comment: Then, unfortunately, this isn't the place to be. We really can't help you if you can't give us something to work with. You say that you "have an image map" and that you are "using the JQuery Dialog widget". You need to at the very least show how you're using these things.

Comment: Gotta learn to walk before you can run buddy.  Start with opening a dialog anywhere first, then link that to the click of a particular imageMap area and then try using the `position` property  of dialog. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your questions a bit more clearly and provide code of what you have done so far. Also the 'JQuery Dialog' that you are referring to is part of jQuery UI and not jQuery. You shouldn't mix those two up.

Still here is a JS Fiddle of something close to what you're trying to do http://jsfiddle.net/kfLz9/3/

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" border="0" width="275" height="95" usemap="#googlemap" alt="" />

<map name="googlemap">
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="0,1,68,73" />
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="68,20,118,70" />
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="118,20,168,70" />
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="169,20,209,95" />
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="212,0,233,75" />
    <area class="maparea" title="" shape="rect" coords="233,20,274,71" />
</map>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $(".maparea").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });
</script>
```

You should probably read the [jQuery UI Dialog Widget API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/).